# Loading a SQL table into a tree

Tags: php, sqlite

I have a SQLite database with a table of 8000 entries. Each row in this table has a "parent" column which refers to another element in the same table.

What would be the most efficient way to load this table into an easier to access tree-variable?

The "recursive" way is too slow:

```
function BuildMap($top = 0)
{
    global $allmap;
    if ($top == 0)
    {
        $q1 = Q("SELECT * FROM ORGCHART WHERE PARENT = 0 ORDER BY NAME ASC");
        while($r1 = $q1->fetchArray())
        {
            // Save to an array code here
            ...            
            BuildMap($r1['ID']);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $q2 = Q("SELECT * FROM ORGCHART WHERE PARENT = ? ORDER BY NAME ASC",array($top));
        while($r2 = $q2->fetchArray())
        {
            // Save to an array code here
            ...            
            BuildMap($r2['ID']);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is too slow here? The query or the loop that builds the map? If it is the latter, what is slow, the fetch or the building of the map? You can check how long things take with a profiler or simply use [microtime()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.microtime).

Comment: @KIKOSoftware the queries. Eventually this function timeouts without completing in nginx.

Comment: OK, then try to read the whole database with one query, fetch all in one go, and only then process the data in PHP. I assume that 8000 rows will easily fit into memory? Doing a single query is a lot faster than 8000 tiny queries.

Comment: I'll make the same comment as @KIKOSoftware . Because, firstly your BuildMap() will trigger many SQL queries which is normal slow. So query of, then build your tree

Comment: You need to fetch all data in a single query and 'build' the tree 'in PHP' (as stated above)